# Using decimals in ArcGIS Raster Calculator tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator, syntax, error-000989

I would like to create a new raster by using the following regression equation in the [Raster Calculator tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/raster-calculator.htm) in ArcGIS 10.3:

```
Outputras=0,000826345+(0,000203494*"Roads_density.tif")
```

("Roads_density.tif" being an existing raster among my set of layers)

However I get the following message error:

```
ERROR 000989 Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1).
```

When I try :

```
Outputras=0,8+0,2*"Roads_density.tif"
```

the message error disappears.

Is it thus a problem related to the presence of too many decimals ? What do I need to do to force ArcGIS to take in account all the decimals?

Comment: When you run the second line of code (the one with less places after the decimal), do you get an output raster the draws and has the correct values?

Comment: Ok apparently I can get a correct output raster (the regression is used for prediction) only if I use 8 (or even 826345) and 2 (or even 203494) instead of 0,000826345 and 0,000203494 ... so it seems to be a decimals' problem. If I create a first raster: Outputras1=826345+(203494*"Roads_density.tif"), then I create a second and final raster: Outputras2="Outputras1"/1000000000, could it be a correct way to obtain what I want?

Comment: Have you tried it using a decimal instead of a comma yet? That may allow you to avoid the extra step. To my knowledge the operation you want to perform shouldn't be limited by having a float as the cell's output data type. When you try running your operation with commas instead, your working with tuples and I think that's what's causing the error.

Comment: You've removed them by multiplying your values by 1000000000, which is probably why it works now. You can't multiply a float and a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you have any decimals in your equation at all. Try replacing your commas (,) with periods (.)

Comment: Glad I could help! You mind marking this as the answer?